# Evaluate $\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{1+5\sqrt{1+...}}}}}$

Tags: calculus, closed-form, radicals, nested-radicals

$\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{1+5\sqrt{1+...}}}}}$

**My Attempt**: I tried to use the regular way.

$A=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{1+5\sqrt{1+...}}}}}$

$A^2=1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{1+5\sqrt{1+...}}}}$

But then I saw that nothing happened twice and I stopped. Any hints?

**It's better to don't use limits but if you used no problem. If there is an answer that doesn't use limits will accept.**

**update1**: The question that look likes this  wants to find the limit but I want a much easier way to solve it. But if there isn't any answer easier answer the limition one will accept.

**update2**: You solve the problem when you know the answer is 3 think that you don't know that the answer is 3 then solve.

Comment: This is a Ramanujan identity... I believe the answer to be $2$

Comment: Can you tell your sloution please?

Comment: Wikipedia describes a simple procedure... using a formula that Ramanujan found: $\sqrt{ax+(n+a)^2+x\sqrt{a(x+n)+(x+a)^2+(x+n)^2\sqrt{\ldots}}}$

Comment: Can you link please?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical under the tab Infinitely Nested Radicals.

Comment: It isn't the exacthy same you can prove without using limit

Comment: @Frank, I have to look up Nested Radicals inside Nested Radicals? At which Nested Radical may I stop?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand what you mean... could you please reword it?

Comment: I tried to play a pun on Nested Radical inside Nested Radical... seems I didn't succeed.

Comment: Re: *It isn't the exactly the same.* Yes, it is. $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{1 + 2 \sqrt{1 + 3 \sqrt{1 + \cdots \sqrt{1 + (n - 1) \sqrt{1 + n}}}}}$ is simply a different way of writing $ \sqrt{1 + 2 \sqrt{1 + 3 \sqrt{1 + \cdots}}} $.

Comment: Yes I know see update1.

Answer (score 6):

**Setting the Scene**

> Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \underbrace{{\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{1+\cdots+n\sqrt{1}}}}}}}_{n \textrm{ times  }}$

Let $$f_n(0)=\sqrt{1+n}$$also that $$f_n(k)=\sqrt{1+(n-k)f_n(k-1)}.$$

Then clearly $0<f_n(0)<n+1$ when $n>0$. Now if we assume that $f_n(k)<n+1-k$ and by induction that we see that
$$
f_n(k+1) < \sqrt{1+(n-k-1)(n-k+1)} = \sqrt{1+(n-k)^2-1} = n+1-(k+1)
$$
for all k. The expression is $f_n(n-2)$ which is increasing in $n$ and bounded above by $3$ and thus converges. Hence

> $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \underbrace{{\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{1+\cdots+n\sqrt{1}}}}}}}_{n \textrm{ times  }}=3$

**EDIT**

Showing that $3$ is the limit can be achieved by writing

\begin{align}
3 &= \sqrt{9} \\
&= \sqrt{1 + 8}\\
 &= \sqrt{1 + 2 \cdot 4} \\
&= \sqrt{1 + 2\sqrt{16}}\\ 
&= \sqrt{1 + 2\sqrt{1 + 3 \cdot 5}}\\
& = \sqrt{1 + 2\sqrt{1 + 3 \sqrt{25}}} \\
&= \sqrt{1 + 2\sqrt{1 + 3 \sqrt{1 + 4 \cdot 6}}}\\
&= \ldots
\end{align}
and so on.

Comment: You haven't shown the limit, you just proved that it converges. It must be shown that the supremum is 3, then the limit is also 3. With the same reasoning I could say the limit is 69, because it is an upper bound.

Comment: How about this: $$4=\sqrt{1+2\cdot \frac {15}{2}}=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\cdot \frac {221}{12}}}=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+\ldots}}}$$Thus, the infinitely nested radical is equal to $4$ too! (A contradiction)

Answer (score 3):

First you can guess that this seems to converge to $3$ by using a calculator (or by estimating the radicals). Assuming the limit is three, then one can try to wrtie $3$ as the following down:

$3=\sqrt{1+8}=\sqrt{1+2\cdot4}=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{16}}=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+15}}=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3*5}}=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{25}}}=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\cdot 6}}}=\ldots$

This iteration is the same as the formula you stated above, because it holds

$\sqrt{n^2}=\sqrt{1+(n-1)(n+1)}=\sqrt{1+(n-1)\sqrt{(n+1)^2}} \quad \forall n\in \mathbb{N}, n>1$

Thus, the limit is $3$.